# Calculate mean and autocovariance for random walk to check stationarity

Tags: time-series, autocorrelation, stationarity, random-walk

[image]

I am confused by the second line and the third line of the autocovariance calculation. Like how the var() and the 0 come, and why there is t*sigma^2 at the end.

Comment: $var(Y)=E[(Y -E[Y])^2]=E[Y^2]-(E[Y])^2$ may help

Comment: How the 0 term come?

Comment: It comes from $E[X_t]=0$ so $(E[X_t])^2=0$ and $E[X_t]E[X_s]=0$

Answer (score 0):

The second term is $\mathbb E\left[\sum_{1\leq j\leq k}Z_j\sum_{1\leq j'\leq k}Z_{t+j'}\right].$ Now $\langle Z_j\rangle$ is a white noise process. That means $\mathbb E[Z_tZ_\tau] =0$ when $t\ne \tau.$ So, the concerned term yields zero.